# system verilog slicing arrays

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am still not sure how the array slicing works in System Verilog?

For example, let's say that I have a packed 2D array.

```
localparam [0:2][4:0] TEMP = {5'd4,5'd9,5'd20};
```

So my array has three rows and each row is a 5-bit number.

So, when I am trying to do something like this, it doesn't quite work !!!

```
logic [1:0] arr;

assign arr = TEMP[0][1:0]
```

How come this doesn't work? 
The compiler doesn't complain, but the simulation shows all 'X !!

Here I am including the module that has the issue:

```
module slice_issue ();

// clock and reset 
reg board_resetl;
reg tb_clkh;
parameter CLK_PER  = 4;


always #(CLK_PER/2) tb_clkh = ~ tb_clkh;

initial begin: main_process
  board_resetl = 0;
  tb_clkh = 0;

  #100 
  @(posedge tb_clkh);  
  board_resetl = 1;

 end



localparam logic [4:0] PARAM_1 = 14;
localparam logic [4:0] PARAM_2 = 18;
localparam logic [4:0] PARAM_3 = 26;

localparam [0:2] [4:0] CAND_MODE_LIST = {PARAM_1, PARAM_2, PARAM_3};

logic [1:0] temp;
logic [4:0] temp2;

logic [1:0] in_pred_mode;

logic [4:0] cnt_reg; 

always @ (posedge tb_clkh or negedge board_resetl) 
    begin  
       if (~board_resetl) begin 
          in_pred_mode <= 0; 
          cnt_reg  <= 0;
       end else  
          cnt_reg  <= cnt_reg + 1; 
       if (cnt_reg == 31) begin
          in_pred_mode <= $urandom_range(0, 1); 
       end
    end

// bad
assign temp  = CAND_MODE_LIST[in_pred_mode][1:0];

// good 
assign temp2  = CAND_MODE_LIST[in_pred_mode];

endmodule
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think the compiler should complain about? Your code looks fine to me. TEMP is a 15 bit parameter and you've assigned with a 15-bit concatenation. Since it is a packed array, the size does not even have to match. The implicit parameter type is `logic` so there could be a race at time 0 before arr assigned; it could still be 'x. You need to show a complete self-contained example.

Comment: I don't know why I got a minus on my question. There is nothing else in my code. that is simply it. Just for a test I put that in a module, and there is not even a sequential process in my code. This simply doesn't work with during simulation. And I was just wondering why? Again there is no warnings or anything, but the result is 'x all the way

Comment: The code you have shown so far will not compile by itself - it is not inside a module or interface. How do you know `arr` is 'x? Where is the $display

Answer (score 0):

A self contained example could be :

```
module tb;

  localparam [0:2][4:0] TEMP = {5'd4,5'd9,5'd20};
  logic [1:0] arr;

  assign arr = TEMP[0][1:0];

  initial begin
    $display("arr : %b", arr);
    #1ps;
    $display(TEMP[0]);
    $display(TEMP[1]);
    $display(TEMP[2]);
    $display("arr : %b", arr);
  end

endmodule
```

For me this (correctly) outputs:

```
# KERNEL: arr : 00
# KERNEL:  4
# KERNEL:  9
# KERNEL: 20
# KERNEL: arr : 00
```

This does not show the error condition from the question, unless the question adds more information, the exact reason for the error can not be determined.

[example on EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/QBq)

Answer (score 0):

instead of negative points, I should've gotten a positive one. I contacted the vendor (Aldec), and it turned out it is Aldec's simulator issue, and they are going to fixed it in their next revision.